# Why is a frozen "enum" slower?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In order to access the data in an array I created an `enum`-like variable to have human readable identifiers to the fields.

```
var columns = { first: 0, second: 1 };
var array = ['first', 'second'];
var data = array[columns.first];
```

When I found out about `Object.freeze` I wanted to use this for the enum so that it can not be changed, and I expected the VM to use this info to its advantage.

As it turns out, the tests get slower on Chrome and Node, but slightly faster on Firefox (compared to direct access by number).

The code is available here: http://jsperf.com/array-access-via-enum

Here are the benchmarks from Node (corresponding to the JSPerf tests):

```
  fixed Number: 12ms
  enum: 12ms
  frozenEnum: 85ms
```

Does V8 just not yet have a great implementation, or is there something suboptimal with this approach for my use-case?

Comment: It seems V8's static code analysis is quite good and translates the `columns` enum access to the fixed numbers. It doesn't do that with the `frozen` enum object as it is mutated by `Object.freeze` - FF seems to be smarter there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your test in Firefox 20, which is massively faster across the board, and IE 10 which slightly faster and more consistant.

So my answer is **No, V8 does not yet have a great implementation**

Comment: And for some technical reasons, the node people sometimes defer some new V8 feature/improvements for a while. Could change in the feature.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [bugreport](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1858#c6), freezing an object currently puts it in "dictionary-mode", which is slow.

So instead of improving the performance, it becomes a definite slowdown for "enums"/small arrays.